# even value in a R.V using generating functions

Tags: probability

Am told no information is missing here.
A random variable $X$ has a probability generating function $G(t)$. Show that $X$ takes an even value is ${1 \over 2}(1 + G(-1))$.

any hint please?

Comment: Is that ${1 \over 2}(1 + G(-1))$ or ${1 \over {2(1 + G(-1))}}$?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions. Please add how you attempted to solve the problem or how stumbled upon this question.

Answer (score 4):

For every non-negative integer $n$, we have $\Pr(X=n)=a_n$, where 
$$G(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3+a_4t_4+a_5t^5+\cdots.$$

The probability that $n$ is even is $a_0+a_2+a_4+\cdots$. It is easy to verify that this is $\frac{1}{2}\left(G(1)+G(-1)\right)$.

Finally, what is the value of $G(1)$?